# Loading each array items in sectioned tableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutablearray in which I have dynamic number of objects.I have to load them in a sectioned tableView with sections.But getting error when trying to assign each object to a section.

```
sections=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int s=0;s<[finalarray count];s++)
    {
        NSMutableArray *section=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        tableViewarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       tableViewarray = [finalarray objectAtIndex:s];

        for(int i=0;i<[tableViewarray count];i++)
        {
            Item *item=[[Item alloc] init];
            NSString *eventName=[[tableViewarray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Date"];//but getting error at this line

            item.TimeStart=eventName;
            [section addObject:item];

        }
        [sections addObject:section];

    }
```

finalArray:

```
(
{
Date="Jan 11";
},
{
Date="Jan 12";
},

(
{
Date="Jan 11";
},
{
Date="Jan 12";
}
Date="Jan 13";
}
)
)
```

Here I have to load two sections :
But getting error:'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance .

How can I add each object and load those many number of sections?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
NSString *eventName=[[[tableViewarray objectAtIndex:s] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Date"];
```